# Is there a way to start a section from a different number than 1 (such as 0 or 11)

Tags: fonts

In my textbook, vector-valued functions is the twelfth chapter, and I would like to be able to make a new document starting from chapter 12. Is there a way I can start the sections in a new document from 12 instead of 1?

Comment: sure simply set the counter, e.g. \setcounter{chapter}{11}.

Comment: Yes, that helps. Thanks!